Conditional in looped task
I want to create tasks that:

create group
create user
provide default entries in authorized_keys file
append ssh_pubkey variable into authorized_keys file if such variable is defined

My task:
- name: Create groups
  ansible.builtin.group:
    name: "{{ item.group }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ role_users_user_details }}"

- name: Create users
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    groups: "{{ item.group }}"
    password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ role_users_user_details }}"

- name: Provide required entry authorized_keys
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: ../files/authorized_keys
    dest: /home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/
    owner: "{{ item.username }}"
    group: "{{ item.username }}"
    mode: '0644'
    backup: true
  loop: "{{ role_users_user_details }}"

- name: Append user pubkey in authorized_keys
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    dest: /home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
    line: "{{ item.ssh_pubkey }}"
    state: present
    insertafter: EOF
  loop: "{{ role_users_user_details }}"
  when: item.ssh_pubkey is defined               <<< Here is the issue

Effect:
TASK [role_users : Append user pubkey in authorized_keys] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: <xxx>
skipping: [xxx] => (item={'username': 'xxx_user', 'group': 'xxx_user', 'ssh_pubkey': 'test'})  => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "false_condition": "item.username.ssh_pubkey is defined",
    "item": {
        "group": "xxx_user",
        "ssh_pubkey": "test",
        "username": "xxx_user"
    },
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"

Meanwhile my vars.yml structure looks like this:
role_users_remote_username: "{{ inventory_hostname + '_' + 'user' }}"

role_users_user_details:
  - username: "{{ role_users_remote_username }}"
    group: "{{ role_users_remote_username }}"
    ssh_pubkey: "test-entry"
  - username: ansible_usr
    group: ansible_usr

The goal is to run task: Append user pubkey in authorized_keys - only for users with ssh_pubkey variable defined.

Please double check the code you copy/pasted because it's obviously not the one you run for the output example. The output very clearly specifies: "false_condition": "item. username .ssh_pubkey is defined". This is the condition you used during run and indeed the result is always False given your data sample. If you use the correct condition pasted in your code (i.e. => item.ssh_pubkey is defined, you should have the expected result.

That being said, it might be more convenient and performant to filter the unwanted entries beforehand: you could drop your condition and use instead loop: "{{ role_users_user_details | selectattr('ssh_pubkey', 'defined') }}"

The same code works when I changed loop to with_items.
 - name: Append user pubkey in authorized_keys
   ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
     dest: /home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
     line: "{{ item.ssh_pubkey }}"
     state: present
     insertafter: EOF
  when: item.sudoers is defined
  with_items: '{{ role_users_user_details }}'


"with_items is replaced by loop and the flatten filter."
